# Как разделить работу между горутинами

Tags: golang, производительность

Имеется большой датасет из картинок

```
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "image/png"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

var (
    Black = color.Gray{0}
)

func getRandFloatNumber(min, max float32) float32 {
    return (rand.Float32()*2 - min) * max
}

func openImage(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    infile, _ := os.Open(path)
    defer infile.Close()
    img, err := png.Decode(infile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    array := make([]float32, 128*128)
    for y := 0; y < 128; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < 128; x++ {
            c := color.GrayModel.Convert(img.At(x, y)).(color.Gray)
            if c == Black {
                array[x*y] = getRandFloatNumber(0.7, 0.95)
            } else {
                array[x*y] = getRandFloatNumber(0.1, 0.25)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    filepath.Walk("./dataset", openImage)
}
```

Написал скрипт который проходится по всем файлам в директории ./dataset и парит картинки. Как можно оптимизировать этот код?

**Update**
Попробовал распаралелить при помощи go-routine

```
go func() {
array := make([]float32, 128*128)
for y := 0; y < 128; y++ {
    for x := 0; x < 128; x++ {
        c := color.GrayModel.Convert(img.At(x, y)).(color.Gray)
        if c == Black {
            array[x*y] = getRandFloatNumber(0.7, 0.95)
        } else {
            array[x*y] = getRandFloatNumber(0.1, 0.25)
        }
    }
}
}()
```

получилось только хуже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очевидно - использовать сильные стороны Go и распределить обработку по нескольким рутинам с использованием простого пула задач.

Comment: именно как это сделать я и спрашиваю, не понимаю как можно запустить в несколько горутин

Answer (score 1):

Комментарии изменений внутри кода.

```
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "image/png"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var (
    Black = color.Gray{0}

    queue       = make(chan string)     // Очередь задач, для распределения нагрузки между воркерами
    WorkerCount = runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0) // количество воркеров. В простом случае посто количество разрешенных потоков
)

func getRandFloatNumber(min, max float32) float32 {
    return (rand.Float32()*2 - min) * max
}

// собственно обработка, внутри не важно что. Смысловую часть функциии не смотрел.
func openImage(path string) error {
    infile, _ := os.Open(path)
    defer infile.Close()
    img, err := png.Decode(infile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    array := make([]float32, 128*128)
    for y := 0; y < 128; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < 128; x++ {
            c := color.GrayModel.Convert(img.At(x, y)).(color.Gray)
            if c == Black {
                array[x*y] = getRandFloatNumber(0.7, 0.95)
            } else {
                array[x*y] = getRandFloatNumber(0.1, 0.25)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// вот тут основные смысловые переделки
func main() {

    /*
        Запускаем в фоне сканирование папок
    */
    go func() {
        // После завершения сканирования - закрываем очередь.
        // Если очередь буферизованная - оставшиеся задачи из очереди будут выполнены.
        defer close(queue)

        filepath.Walk("./dataset", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            queue <- path
            return nil
        })
    }()

    // Группа синхронизации нужна для того чтобы дождаться завершения работы всех фоновых обработчиков.
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(WorkerCount)

    // Запускаем фновых обработчиков
    for i := 0; i < WorkerCount; i++ {
        go func() {
            // по окончании функции обработчик отмечается о завершении работы
            defer wg.Done()

            // Этот цикл берёт из канала задачи, пока они там есть. При закрытии канала цикл просто завершается
            // Если канал буферизованный - после его закрытия сначала получаются оставшиеся задачи и цикл завершается
            // после того как все задачи получены.
            for task := range queue {

                // собственно вызов смысловой обработки
                openImage(task)
            }
        }()
    }

    // Это важная строка - тут мы ждём пока завершится фоновая обработка. Иначе программа будет завершена сразу после
    // запуска фоновых обработчиков
    wg.Wait()
}
```